# Terminating Dialogflow Application from Custom Client

Tags: go, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I created a custom Golang server to handle Dialogflow's fulfillment. I want my fulfillment server to tell Dialogflow (which would be running the compiled version on a Google home) to terminate my action after a certain period of inactivity. Is this possible in the current architecture?

Comment: Is this for an action, or a different dialogflow integration?

Comment: Hi Nick, this is for action.

Answer (score 1):

To mark the end of an Action and close it, you can return `false` for the [`expectUserResponse`](https://developers.google.com/actions/build/json/dialogflow-webhook-json#dialogflow-end-conversation-example) field, like:

```
{
  "payload": {
  "google": {
    "expectUserResponse": false,
    "richResponse": {
      "items": [
        {
          "simpleResponse": {
            "textToSpeech": "Goodbye!"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
 }
}
```